# JS Using objects dinamic keynames

Tags: javascript, object

I need to use object which contains my settings, mainly keynames assignment. But I cant figure out why it does not work

```
//This is my object which contains names of the keys of another object
let setup={
  param1:'data1',
  param2: 'data2'
}

//So here is the main object where I need to use values as a keynames
const StatDataObj = {
  DataFields: {
    ['setup.param1']: {Blocks: [],Patch: []},
    ['setup.param1']: {Blocks: [],Patch: []}
  }
}
```

Everything seems quite simple but it gives me error! So what im doing wrong?

Comment: remove the quotes in `'setup.param1' ` since now the object will take the string `'setup.param1' ` as the key not `data1`.  using `[setup.param1]` will give you `data1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const setup = { param1:'data1', param2: 'data2' };

const StatDataObj = {
  DataFields: {
    [setup.param1]: { Blocks: [], Patch: [] },
    [setup.param2]: { Blocks: [], Patch: [] }
  }
};

console.log(StatDataObj);
```

Comment: Hmm strange the Run code snippet shows that everything works ok. But im still getting Script completed with error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (9:15)

Comment: @Syngltake can you share a fiddle to your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you adding string, not variable value

```js
//This is my object which contains names of the keys of another object
let setup={
  param1:'data1',
  param2: 'data2'
}

//So here is the main object where I need to use values as a keynames
const StatDataObj = {
  DataFields: {
    [setup.param1]: {Blocks: [],Patch: []},
    [setup.param1]: {Blocks: [],Patch: []}
  }
}

console.log(StatDataObj)
```